# How to use Photoshop's 'Save for Web' with the new CC2015 artboard feature?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud

Adobe implemented artboards into Photoshop CC 2015. This is a fantastic addition. However, the now-classified 'legacy' Save for Web feature doesn't actually understand them.

In Illustrator SfW, there is an option to honor the working space of artboards and only export content within their confines. However, in the new Photoshop, there doesn't seem to be such an option. When you hit 'Save for Web', it attempts to save the entire working space as the image.

Only workaround I have found thus far is to right click on the artboard's name in the layers panel and 'export'. However, I'm prompted with a very restrictive options panel that even seems to use a Windows 3.1 era serif that doesn't exactly instil confidence.

Any ideas? Thoughts? Help?

Thanks! This is my first post here.

Comment: They're trying to push everybody to use 'export as' as opposed to save for web. My panel doesn't have a serif font. Though it seems to take quite a bit longer to load for some reason.

Comment: Hi Nathen, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Can you please provide some more info on what you’d like to export? Would you like an image for each artboard? Which options do you need that aren’t in Export As?